# change element name and remove attribute using linq and c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have a task where i need to convert xml to xhtml.

after some trial and error. im going to use c# 
and i also read some linq to xml articles

what im trying to do here is changed the element name based on its attribute

this is my xml input

```
<p><tada><Emphasis Type="Italic">q</Emphasis>-analogues of <Emphasis Type="Italic">n</Emphasis></tada>
<tada><todo><Emphasis Type="Italic">abc</Emphasis></todo></tada></p>
```

and this is the possible output

```
<p>
  <tada>
    <i>q</i>-analogues of <i>n</i></tada>
  <tada>
    <todo>
      <i>abc</i>
    </todo>
  </tada>
</p>
```

and so far this is my c# code

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\Desktop\trial.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> Emphasis =
                from el in root.Descendants("Emphasis")
                where (string)el.Attribute("Type") == "Italic"
                select el;
            foreach (XElement el in Emphasis)
            {
                el.Name = "i";

            }
            Console.WriteLine(root.ToString());
```

and this is the output

```
<p>
  <tada>
    <i Type="Italic">q</i>-analogues of <i Type="Italic">n</i></tada>
  <tada>
    <todo>
      <i Type="Italic">abc</i>
    </todo>
  </tada>
</p>
```

the ouput is wrong because it doesn't remove the attribute

Comment: Try `el.Attribute("Type").Remove()`